# Configure WebLogic application/Web Application to not use MOXy for JAXB

Tags: jaxb, weblogic, moxy

My company has a Web Application that uses the JAXB provider in the JDK
The application runs great in Tomcat.
We have a customer that want to to use WebLogic

The application fails when trying to create a JAXBContext.

This page https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#WSGET347

documents how to configure a WebLogic application to not use MOXy for JAXB

When I use the "Global" solution, modifying the startup script to prepend modules/databinding.override.jar to the classpath, my Web App works fine

This is a rather large hammer as the customer has existing apps on an existing server and we are targeting that server.

When I try the Application level solution, no luck.

Any pointers as to where I going wrong?

[Eclipse Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XUZV.png)